# How to remove blank space between some words using sed?

Tags: linux, sed, vi

I want to replace characters between specific words in a line (multiple lines). for example:

```
first second third |         first line
first second third |  second line
first second third |    third line 
first second third |                forth line 
....
```

I want to replace characters between third and first/second/third/forth etc...using sed or vi in linux.

If this question is already answered, can you please provide me the link?
Thanks!

Comment: You received three different answers because you don't specify what to replace with: a single space, nothing, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
sed  's/ |.[^a-z]*//g' text.txt
```

or if you want to have a space after 'third':

```
sed  's/ |.[^a-z]*/ /g' text.txt
```

remember about the **-i** flag to make permanent changes.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i  's/\ /whatever/g' ej.txt`

-i: in file, means that changes are made directly in the file

-s: substitute

-'\ ': to recognize blank space

-g: all matches on each line

Comment: You don't need to escape the space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sed 's/second third[^a-zA-Z]*/second third/g' file
```

It will replace everything between third and this first letter. And if it works use -i if you want to modify the original file